# SQL VIEW Unsupported Data Type

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create a SQL View that pulls 2 tables together each from a different DB.  The SQL works fine in the query editor but when I try to run it as a view all the columns from the MSP_EpmProject table say "Unsupported DataType".

```
SELECT     TOP (200) dbo.Project.ProjectID, dbo.Project.ProjectGUID, dbo.Project.ProjectName, dbo.Project.DefaultBaselineID, 
                      FMM_ProjectServer_Reporting.dbo.MSP_EpmProject.ProjectName AS Expr1
FROM         dbo.Project INNER JOIN
                      FMM_ProjectServer_Reporting.dbo.MSP_EpmProject ON dbo.Project.ProjectGUID = FMM_ProjectServer_Reporting.dbo.MSP_EpmProject.ProjectUID
```

Comment: FMM_ProjectServer_Reporting is a linked server im guessing? What SQL server version are both servers running?

Comment: There both running on SQL 2012 on the same server

Comment: There is no solution even with SQL Server 2016 and MS says they are not able to reproduce this problem and hence unable to solve this problem, however, what I have noticed is that if you have rows with similar data, then this problem occurs. As soon as you get rid of duplicate data, it is not there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out this bug report - http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/464339/unsupported-data-type-reported-for-supported-data-types-in-nested-query

It appears to be a long standing issue from SQL 2005 which they still havent fixed.

The work around appears to be to not work with your view in design mode, you will have to develop this view manually in query analyzer.

Comment: Potential shortcut...use design mode to get the view you want (with "erroneous" data types), and then...

1. Right-click the view, "Script View As Alter To..."
2. Execute the query

SELECT the view without opening designer again - everything should look good. :)